# How to calculate score using Radio buttons in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have been developing a form which uses Radio buttons and has a list of questions.

When the user clicks on Yes radio button for every question, I want to increment the score by 20. If the user clicks the No radio button, the score should be 0.

Take a look at the code.

This is the Activity class

### CoughTest.java

```
  public class CoughTest extends AppCompatActivity {

    int score= 0;
    RadioGroup rg1,rg2,rg3,rg4,rg5;
    RadioButton rb;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cough_test);

        rg1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgroup1);
        rg2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgroup2);
        rg3 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgroup3);
        rg4 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgroup4);
        rg5 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgroup5);
    }


    public void rbClicked(View view) {
        int radioButtonId = rg1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        rb =(RadioButton) findViewById(radioButtonId);

        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.yes1:
                score = score + 20;
                break;
            case R.id.no1:
                score = 0;
                break;
            case R.id.yes2:
                score = score + 20;
                break;
            case R.id.no2:
                score = 0;
                break;
            case R.id.yes3:
                score = score + 20;
                break;
            case R.id.no3:
                score = 0;
                break;
            case R.id.yes4:
                score = score + 20;
                break;
            case R.id.no4:
                score = 0;
                break;
            case R.id.yes5:
                score = score + 20;
                break;
            case R.id.no5:
                score = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the XML file

### activity_cough_test.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CoughTest">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
            android:text="Do you have a cough?"
            android:textColor="#100D40"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/rgroup1">
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/yes1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                android:onClick="rbClicked"
                android:text="Yes"
                android:textColor="#100D40" />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/no1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:onClick="rbClicked"
                android:text="No"
                android:textColor="#100D40" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/soar_throat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
            android:text="Do you have a soar throat?"
            android:textColor="#100D40"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/rgroup2">
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/yes2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                android:onClick="rbClicked"
                android:text="Yes"
                android:textColor="#100D40" />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/no2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:onClick="rbClicked"
                android:text="No"
                android:textColor="#100D40" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fever"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
            android:text="Do you have fever?"
            android:textColor="#100D40"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/rgroup3">
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/yes3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                android:onClick="rbClicked"
                android:text="Yes"
                android:textColor="#100D40" />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/no3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:onClick="rbClicked"
                android:text="No"
                android:textColor="#100D40" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tiredness"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
            android:text="Do you have tiredness?"
            android:textColor="#100D40"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/rgroup4">
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/yes4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                android:onClick="rbClicked"
                android:text="Yes"
                android:textColor="#100D40" />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/no4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:onClick="rbClicked"
                android:text="No"
                android:textColor="#100D40" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/breathing"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
            android:text="Do you have difficulty in breathing?"
            android:textColor="#100D40"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/rgroup5">
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/yes5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                android:onClick="rbClicked"
                android:text="Yes"
                android:textColor="#100D40" />
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/no5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:onClick="rbClicked"
                android:text="No"
                android:textColor="#100D40" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: you need variable for save score and you do that. what's exactly you problem?

Comment: I have created a variable for score and have incremented the value by 20. I have also set the text to a textView but its not coming.So what should i do now?

Comment: @PranavKumar using cases here won't be a good idea. Also using 2 buttons [yes/no] is lengthy than using only 1 radio button to check is user response is yes. Please check my solution.

Comment: Why are you using radio button. Useally this kind of senario using check box it the best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest this method:

**CoughTest.java:**

```
public class CoughTest extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btnSubmit, btnReset;
private TextView finalScore;
private RadioButton cough, sourThroat, fever, tiredness, breathing;

private  int score = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cough_test);

    btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
    btnReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReset);
    finalScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textFinalScore);

    cough = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.cough);
    sourThroat = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.sour_throat);
    fever = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.fever);
    tiredness = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.tiredness);
    breathing = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.breathingDifficulty);

    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (cough.isChecked()) {
                score = score + 20;
            } else {
                score = score + 0;
            }

            if (sourThroat.isChecked()) {
                score = score + 20;
            } else {
                score = score + 0;
            }

            if (fever.isChecked()) {
                score = score + 20;
            } else {
                score = score + 0;
            }

            if (tiredness.isChecked()) {
                score = score + 20;
            } else {
                score = score + 0;
            }

            if (breathing.isChecked()) {
                score = score + 20;
            } else {
                score = score + 0;
            }

            //Finally show your score.
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Score is: " + score, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
            //Resetting everything
    btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            score = 0;
            cough.setChecked(false);
            fever.setChecked(false);
            breathing.setChecked(false);
            tiredness.setChecked(false);
            sourThroat.setChecked(false);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Coming back to your XML: I modified it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CoughTest">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".CoughTest">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                android:text="Please check (✓) if you show the symptom."
                android:textColor="#100D40"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/cough"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                android:text="cough"
                android:textColor="#100D40" />


            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/sour_throat"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                android:text="Sour Throat"
                android:textColor="#100D40" />


            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/fever"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                android:text="Fever"
                android:textColor="#100D40" />


            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/tiredness"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                android:text="tiredness"
                android:textColor="#100D40" />


            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/breathingDifficulty"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                android:text="Breathing Difficulty"
                android:textColor="#100D40" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="submit"
                android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
                android:layout_marginStart="50sp"/>
            <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Reset"
            android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
            android:id="@+id/btnReset"
            android:layout_marginStart="50sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
                android:hint="Your Score Here"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:id="@+id/textFinalScore"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have removed the radio groups. Just prompt your user to click it when they agree.
Means if their answer is YES, then please check the radio button else leave it unchecked.
Hope that helps.

By the way this is how it works:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

just set score into your textView after your switch case :

```
yourTextView = String.ValueOf(score);
```